# How can i load database content via ajax before a filter keyup is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this codes below. It works when a filter parameter is presssed on keyup. but i need the content of the database to load via ajax as soon as the page is ready even when no filter search is initiated.
here are my codes

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {

               var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
                 $.post('actionSessionsearch.php', {search_term: search_term}, function(data){
                         $('.divDisplay').html(data);
                     });
               });

           });

   </script>
```

php

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/dc_conect.php');

if((!isset($_POST['search_term'])==true) and (!isset($_POST['search_term'])!=NULL)){
     echo "hoho";
}
else
{    $search_term=$_POST['search_term'];

        $sqlSession = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_name LIKE '%$search_term%'";
        $resultSession=mysql_query($sqlSession, $link) or die (mysql_error());
        $dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession);
        $countSession=mysql_num_rows($resultSession);
        do{
            echo $dbfieldSession['session_name'].'<br>';
        }while($dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession));

}
?>
```

it only retireves when i enter a value into the search box. I want to have my database details display even when the filter has not been initiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do following things:

**PHP**

```
if((!isset($_POST['search_term'])==true) and (!isset($_POST['search_term'])!=NULL)){
 /* Load data from Database here, something like SELECT * FROM sessions;*/
}
else
{    $search_term=$_POST['search_term'];

    $sqlSession = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_name LIKE '%$search_term%'";
    $resultSession=mysql_query($sqlSession, $link) or die (mysql_error());
    $dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession);
    $countSession=mysql_num_rows($resultSession);
    do{
        echo $dbfieldSession['session_name'].'<br>';
    }while($dbfieldSession=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSession));

}
```

**JS**

Call your AJAX function inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})` and use `$.get` instead of `$.post`

Comment: Wachtler did as instructed with the $.get and it worked

Comment: when i delete the search parameters in the filter box. i will like it to go back to the original record displayed in load. You have ny clue on dat?

Comment: Maybe sort of detect if search box value is empty (on keyup, because the last character gets deleted by backspace). if yes, just perform same request as on doc.ready, you could create a function for a request of all data. But be aware, loading the data everytime directly from the database is not a best practice. You should store the returned data temporary if it's not being changed very often.

Comment: ohk. thnks. i am i to check if it empty from the serverside or do dat from the ajax. if its from the ajax. how do i call a function to see if the filter box is empty on keyup. am quit new to it

Comment: Just use an `if-statement` on your search box inside keyup function, `var searchTerm=$.trim($("YOURCHECKBOXIDENTIFIER").val());` after that set up an `if-statement` and check if `searchTerm.length > 0`

Comment: ramis. i really cnt put them together. i tried search_term=$.trim($(".autoresponder").val());

Comment: i might just try n play arround the server-side to see if i cn go arround it

Comment: i was able to achieve it as instructed with jquery from the front end. very greatful